# Semantic's Popup does not show up when passing a custom component as trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am quite simply trying to make a toggle button component with an optional `popupContent` to either render just the button or alternatively have it inside of a  `<Popup />` component (`semantic-ui-react`), i.e., have a tooltip show up on hover. I ran into a problem where my component works correctly if I define the button in the `trigger` prop of `Popup` but not if I make the button into a separate component and pass that to the prop.

Working example:

```
return (
  <Popup
    content={popupContent}
    trigger={
      <Button onClick={updateFilters} size="mini" icon basic={!active} primary={active}>
        <Icon name="filter" />
      </Button>
    }
  />
)
```

What I would like to do - works otherwise but the popup does not show up:

```
const Toggle = () => (
  <Button onClick={updateFilters} size="mini" icon basic={!active} primary={active}>
    <Icon name="filter" />
  </Button>
)

return popupContent ? <Popup content={popupContent} size="mini" trigger={<Toggle />} /> : <Toggle />
```

Please note that I have tried this without the ternary; it is not the culprit. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you add your code here: http://react.new/

Comment: Here's the whole component in a working state: https://github.com/UniversityOfHelsinkiCS/oodikone/blob/ffe1c17c0a9341b05968fed0ae5114bca57ec2ad/services/oodikone2-frontend/src/components/FilterTray/ExternalFilterToggle.jsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem is related to this issue: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/1413

The solution was to wrap the `trigger` node in a `<div>` (for me, `<span>` messed up the tooltip's positioning).

```
return popupContent ? (
  <Popup
    content={popupContent}
    size="mini"
    trigger={
      <div>
        <Toggle />
      </div>
    }
  />
) : (
  <Toggle />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not correct, "the problem" with custom component is that you are not propogate the passed props.

`Popup` component is passing props to the trigger component, which it should handle, when you not handle them, it won't work :].

Change your custom `Toggle` to something like this:

```js
const Toggle = (props) => (
  <Button
    {...props}
    onClick={() => console.log("button-clicked")}
    size="mini"
    icon="filter"
    basic={true}
    primary={true}
  />
);
```

A working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-forked-0ftrc?file=/index.js